# angular 2 listen/detect dom rendered elements from *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to detect/listen an event/hook when angular 2 finishes rendering dom elements initiated from *ngFor?

e.g. I have this list:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <img [src]="item.url">
  </li>
</ul>
```

items are initially empty and filled after http req. is done:

```
items = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('start')
  this.svc.getItems() // http service call
    .subscribe(
      items => {
        this.items = items;
        console.log('done');
      },
      err => this.handleError(err)
    );
}
```

I need to display some sort of loading between 'start' and 'done'. I supposed that when it is logged 'done', then everything is done, but it is not. It takes a while to *ngFor to render elements and fetch images.

**So is there a way to detect that *ngFor is done and images are fetched?**

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/rcNm54oVWeLPkpBwUAsw?p=preview

Comment: this works but it is kinda dirty I'd say :)  I'd need more general approach that could be used in different components (eg. elems like video, audio, img). thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook. `*ngFor` also always updates when `items` change.

What you can do is to call `detectChanges`

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('start')
  this.svc.getItems() // http service call
    .subscribe(
      items => {
        this.items = items;
        console.log('done');
      },
      err => this.handleError(err),
      () => {
         this.cdRef.detectChanges();
         console.log('done')
      }
    );
}
```

As far as I know this synchronically causes the DOM to be updated.

For your use case you can omit `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` because Angular2 will run change detection anyway immediately after `console.log('done')` is called in the completed callback.

Comment: this way first 'done' is logged but after that it takes a while to render added items (fetch images) so if I hide loader there will be time "gap" and will user see no images and no loader

Comment: Can you please try to inject `ApplicationRef` and call its `tick()` instead?

Comment: in complete block? if so then this block is not called because I'm using BehaviourSubject in a middle service between component and http. however next block is called two times..when images are loaded, that's strange...

Comment: Ok, my bad. in that middle svc with BehaviourSubject I initially nexted empty items.. so now I don't see any delay between items added to component's property and loaded images. I think that this delay may occur on devices with slow inet connection.